# Angles between curves

Tags: derivatives

Question: Find the angle between the curves $y = \sin 5x$ and $y = \cos 5x$ .

I have used the formula $ \tan\theta =\left| \dfrac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1 m_2}  \right|    $

and found the gradient values by deriving each function.
I get an angle of 27.124 degrees. But the answer in the book says : 31.6 degrees ?

Comment: The angle at *which point*?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : I would guess it means at the points where the two graphs intersect each other. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I assumed so in my solution, below.

Answer (score 1):

You must solve for the intersection point of the two curves:

$\sin (5 x) = \cos (5 x)$, or $\sin (5 x) = \sin (\pi/2 - 5 x)$, which gives $x = \pi/20 = .15708$.

Then take derivatives:

${d \sin (5 x) \over dx} = 5 \cos (5 x)$, and likewise for the other function.  Substitute the value of $x$ at the intersection to get the slopes.  Then use your formula.

The answer is indeed $31.5863^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it by first looking at the angle between $\sin x$ and $cos x$

clearly they intersect at $\frac \pi 4$ where the slopes of the tangents are $\pm \frac {1}{ \sqrt 2}$

So the angle we are looking for is $a=2 \tan^{-1}( \frac {1}{ \sqrt 2} )$

For the problem stated we have $x \to 5 x$ which represents a horizontal contraction by a factor of $5$ so all slopes are multiplied by $5$

So the angle is given by ...

$$ a= 2 \tan^{-1}( \frac {5}{ \sqrt 2})  $$

notice that $180-a=31.56^\circ$

note: this question gives the answer in degrees and yet clearly expects the arguments of the Sin and Cos functions to be in radians.

Comment: You don't need to write $31.56^o$; you can write $31.56^\circ$.  I edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, the point of intersection of the curves $y=\sin 5x$ & $y=\cos 5x$ is found as $$\sin 5x=\cos 5x\implies \tan 5x=1$$ $$5x=\frac{\pi}{4}\ \ \ or  \ \ x=\frac{\pi}{20}$$

the slopes of the tangents at the point of intersection of curves, $x=\pi/20$,  are determined as follows 
$$m_1=\frac{d}{dx}(\sin 5x)=5\cos 5x=5\cos\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{5}{\sqrt2}$$
$$m_2=\frac{d}{dx}(\cos 5x)=-5\sin 5x=5\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=-\frac{5}{\sqrt2}$$
hence, the angle between the curves $$\tan\theta=\tan^{-1}\left|\frac{\frac{5}{\sqrt2}-\left(-\frac{5}{\sqrt2}\right)}{1+\frac{5}{\sqrt2}\left(-\frac{5}{\sqrt2}\right)}\right|=\color{red}{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{10\sqrt 2}{23}\right)\approx 31.5863^\circ}$$